# override include block as_json

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models in a 1:n relation (view and urls).
urls contains url, state, mode. and there will be exact 5 urls will be mapped to view.

suppose I have 5 records in urls table

```
|id | view_id | url    | state     | mode  |
| 1 | 1       |abc.com | recent    | abc   |
| 2 | 1       |cde.com | current   | 123   |
| 3 | 1       |efg.com | current   | def   |
| 4 | 1       |xyz.com | current   | 456   |
| 5 | 1       |nmo.com | recent    | xyz   |



class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :urls, dependent: :destroy

  def as_json options={}
    super(only: [], include: {urls: {only: [:url, :state, :mode]}})
  end
end
```

But overide json did not work for me.

Expected json would be like

```
{
  current: {
    123: cde.com,
    def: efg.com,
    456:xyz.com
  },
  recent: {
    abc: abc.com,
    xyz: nom.com
}
```

I dont know how to get this json by overriding as_json.
}

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do here? Bit confusing , by looking at the expected JSON that you've posted. It seems that you want a JSON with state value as keys and then mode as again keys and url as values.

Comment: yes, it is possible to do it with overriding as_jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find two ways of doing this

```
def as_json
    json = super(only: [], include: {urls: {only: [:url, :state, :mode]}})
    resource = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
    json["urls"].each do |data|
        resource[ data["state"].to_sym ][ data["mode"].to_sym ] = data["url"]
    end
    resource
end
```

and

```
def as_resource
    resource = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
    urls.each do |data|
        resource[ data.state.to_sym ][ data.mode.to_sym ] = data.url
    end
    resource
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just doing something like that:

```
def as_json(options={})
  urls.inject(Hash.new{|hash, state| hash[state]={}}) do |memo, url|
    memo[url.state][url.mode] = url.url
    memo
  end.to_json
end
```